# Update a select list in a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following markup on my page

```
<td colspan="2">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID)%></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="85%">
            <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, Model.CustomerList, new { id = "customerSelect", style = "width: 380px" })%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "*")%>
        </td>
        <td width="15%"><button id="btnAddCustomer" style="font-size: 0.7em;">Add new Customer</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

When the user click on the `btnAddCustomer` a modal dialog is open with the form to add a new customer. It compile the form  and then press the save button.

How can I refresh the select element to include the latest added customer and select it?

Should I use ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up on using JSON to get the options and added to select using jquery manipulation

The following code does the tricks

```
function refreshCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '<%= Url.Content("~/Contact/GetCustomers") %>',
        async: false,
        data: AddAntiForgeryToken({}),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#customerSelect').html('');
            $.each(response, function (i, customer) {
                $('#customerSelect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", customer.Value).text(customer.Text));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view for the table. After the customer is added (using your modal form), use Ajax to update the html of your main view by requesting the partial view.

Example:

On your main view;

```
<td colspan="2">
   <div id="addCustomer" />
</td>
```

in your javascript using jquery after the customer is added:

```
$.get("/Home/AddCustomerPartialView", function (data) { $("#addCustomer").html(data) });
```

The view AddCustomerPartialView.ascx:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<tr><td colspan="2"><%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID)%></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td width="85%">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, Model.CustomerList, new { id = "customerSelect", style = "width: 380px" })%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "*")%>
    </td>
    <td width="15%"><button id="btnAddCustomer" style="font-size: 0.7em;">Add new Customer</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult AddCustomerPartialView()
{
// get your model if need to
return View(yourdata);
}
```